# How to debug ExtJS 4 code with firebug (in Firefox)

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, extjs4, firebug

I've been trying to debug javascript (namely ExtJS 4.0.7) code with firebug (in Firefox browser), but when I set breakpoints and refresh the page, breakpoints disappear and no debugging happens.

What am I missing?

**EDIT :**

I am using Firefox 19.0.2, Windows 7, Firebug 1.11.2.

Breakpoints do not work in controller .js files.

Comment: What version of FF are you using, what's your platform and what's the Firebug plugin version?

Comment: @MaxLeske Firefox 19.0.2, Windows 7, Firebug 1.11.2

Comment: What happens when you try that with other scripts? Do the breakpoints still disappear? Do you control that script? Does it's name or url change upon reload (e.g. to prevent caching)?

Comment: @MaxLeske On client-side I use only javascript. Debugging works fine with pure javascript and ExtJS < (less than) version 4. I have problems with ExtJS 4.0.7. 
Url doesn't change.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the cache of FF? If you haven't, install http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/ and disable all caches from there.

Comment: @MaxLeske Installed, disabled entire cache, disabled DNS cache, debugging still doesn't work.

Comment: Just to make sure that nothing is cached: on the WebDeveloper toolbar click "Miscellaneous" then "Clear private data" and then "Clear all private data...".

Comment: @MaxLeske Quite strange case: as you know ExtJS 4 works on MVC architecture [link](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/application_architecture). I have examined and found that debugging works in app.js file, but it doesn't work in controller (.js) files.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27393/discussion-between-max-leske-and-user1080381)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have probabli enabled ExtJs feature to prevent caching of js files. Look for disableCache config option in ExtJs docs. If it is set to true, ExtJs adds timestamp as param to each loaded file (you ca see ?_dc=123456789 in Firebug Net panel. File is always new and firebug is not able to set breakpoints after reload.

Comment: Solution: I set disableCaching option to false in Loader.setConfig() method (file: ext-all-dev.js, line: 10343)

Comment: However this solution has some cons: when the .js file is changed it is not updated in browser, you still need to disable caching for the changes to take effect (windows xp, firefox 19.0.2, IIS 5.1). p.s. Works fine in Win 7

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the **debugger** statement in your code to stop the execution in that spot.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/0bwt76sk(v=vs.94).aspx